# Leveraging both GraphQL and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

Is it possible to leverage both GraphQL and Mongoose?

So far, I have been able to integrate both GraphQL and Mongoose to handle populating the database, but I am struggling to understand how this can work to retrieve data, specifically data with nested references.

Consider this schema:

```
const fooSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: 'String', required: true },
  bar: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Bar',
    required: false,
  }],
});
```

The Bar schema is essentially the same, with just a field for "name".

Is it possible to run a GraphQL query to populate the data with the references in 'bar'?

Currently, we are using GraphQL-Tools to create our typeDefs, Mutations, and Queries which looks something like this:

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Foo {
    name: String!,
    bars:[Bar] 
  }
  type Bar {
    _id: ID,
    name: String,
  }

  type Query {
    allFoos: [Foo!]!
    foo(_id: ID!): Foo
  }

  type Mutation {
    ...
  }
`;
module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers});
```

And finally a query directive that looks like this:

```
const allFoos = async (root, data) => {
  return await Foo.find({});
};
```

I am able to change the query directive to use .populate() to get Bar, but that does not actually end up populating the results, which I think is because of the way the typeDefs are set up.

So is it possible to make these two concepts work together? Does it even make sense to use them both?

Comment: *which I think is because of the way the typeDefs are set up*, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As they describe GraphQL:

> GraphQL is a query language for your API, and a server-side runtime
>   for executing queries by using a type system you define for your data.
>   GraphQL isn't tied to any specific database or storage engine and is
>   instead backed by your existing code and data.

Where as mongoose is

> Writing MongoDB validation, casting and business logic boilerplate is
>   a drag. That's why we wrote Mongoose

Monogoose work with mongodb validation whereas graphql is a query language for the API.

You can read a basic example from [here](https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/setting-up-a-simple-graphql-server-with-node-express-and-mongoose-ff8a1071af53) about Setting up a simple GraphQL Server with Node, Express and Mongoose.

These two are completely different. Mongoose work when you are performing any operation on database, whereas grapgl comes in picture when you call a API. Graphql validate your API input parameter and return parameter. If you are adding these two in single app. It will work well.

1. Mongoose will validate your db operation.
2. GraphQL will validate your API input and output parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have seen that example, but still am failing to grasp how I can call and populate my mongo references.

Comment: You have to call your mongo reference as normal call through your resolvers.

Comment: GraphQl is nothing related to mongo call. You just need user your model instance to perform db operation.

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/Gethyl/e0a1d17d873c2c94e0044c61f93896c8#file-schema-js-L59

Comment: Thank you - this was enough to guide me to get what I was looking for.

Comment: @PankajJatav How can I convert my existing rest API to graphQl API?